# Is there a way using divide and conquer to calculate how many times array has changed sign

Tags: c++, algorithm

Suppose there is an array A = {1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1} is there a way to calculate how many times the element of the array changed sign using divide and conquer? e.g: from -1 to 1 and 1 to -1.

I have tried to implement a solution that divides the array into 2 sub-array and calculate whether the last element of the left sub array multiplied by the right element of the right sub array is less than 0, in that case the sign changed.

This is the pseudocode I'm trying to implement:

```
Find Number of Roots(vector V)
  n = V.size()  
  if n <= 1
    return 0
  end if
else
  number_of_roots = 0
  lower_half = Roots(V[1...n/2])
  upper_half = Roots(V[n/2+1...n])

  if (lower_half.back() * upper_half.front() < 0)
  number_of_roots++

  return number_of_roots
 end else
end program
```

Comment: What makes you consider a divide and conquer algorithm for this straight forward loop-once problem?

Comment: You're overthinking the problem. Just use a normal loop. :)

Comment: In short: yes, you can make a divide-and-conquer algorithm, but unless the purpose is to distribute the task over several processors, there is no point in doing so.

Comment: What kind of answer do you need? The simple answer is "Yes." Beyond that, would you like a reasoning or a code solution? In both cases please demonstrate some own research effort by describing your thinking and your coding attempts. How close did you get? What is missing? At least you should have some code which does the "divide" part and applies some NOP to each of the parts. I ask this of you, because I get the impression that this is a homework assignment question and those get routinely closed for being too broad if they do not contain this information.

Comment: In case of this being homework, pleae study and apply the compromise described here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions The same applies to anybody planning on answering...

Comment: this is for numerical analysis, i wanted to optimize the current O(n log n) solution to find root of a curve. I think it would be helpful if someone optimized it into O(log^2 n).

Comment: @muhammed: if you know nothing about the vector `V`, then you must check every element, and you cannot do that faster than O(n). (I don't know why O(n log n) would be necessary.) If there is an O(log n) solution, it will be because `V` is constrained in some way. It's impossible to provide a solution without knowing what the constraints are. (Assuming they exist.)